# App crashes when an uploaded large image is sent to the next activity

Tags: java, android

I have searched through google and even youtube for videos. The code works perfectly when uploading and displaying the large image but crashes when sending it to the next activity. I have tried images with smaller quality or size and it worked perfectly

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 123;
    public static Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    }

    public void upload(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        // Show only images, no videos or anything else
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            switch (requestCode) {
                case PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST:

                    Uri filePath = data.getData();
                    try {
                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.i("TAG", "Some exception" + e);
                    }
                    break;
            }
    }


    public void Submit(View view) {     
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
        if(bitmap !=null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            intent.putExtra("bitmap", byteArray);
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This is where the image sent from the **MainActivity.java** is displayed:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgg);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("bitmap");

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            if (byteArray != null) {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 3244812 byte allocation with 1765075 free bytes and 1723KB until OOM
```

Comment: Error is obvious. you are run out of memory!

Comment: So, what is the way out? I have been stuck all day

Comment: I tried pick a picture from the gallery that was compressed by facebook and whatsapp respectively and it worked. Pls, how can I compress like whatsapp or facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send big image via Intent, from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles.html):

> When sending data via an intent, you should be careful to limit the
>   data size to a few KB. Sending too much data can cause the system to
>   throw a TransactionTooLargeException exception.

So, it's better if you send the **Uri** and process the Uri in the receiver Activity.

First, you need to send the Uri instead of Bitmap in the First Activity:

```
private Uri mFileUri;
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
     switch (requestCode) {
       case PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST:
         // Save uri for submit process.
         mFileUri = data.getData();
         ...
         break;
     }
}

public void Submit(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
  intent.setData(mFileUri);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then handle it in your receiver activity:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgg);

    // get the fileUri from the intent
    Uri fileUri = getIntent().getData();

    try {
      Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
      img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
      // handle the exception.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but still the same problem.  I tried to pick a picture from the gallery that was compressed by facebook and whatsapp respectively and it worked. Pls, how can I compress like whatsapp or facebook

Answer (score 1):

The answers simple. Store the image in a the devices file storage, pass the Uri of the image in storage to the Intent that is launching another activity, then fetch the Uri from said intent, and load from the file.

Comment: I just want to reduce the image size. Or I should display an error message saying "this file is to large for the user, try another picture" when user uploads images large than 2MB

Comment: Tell you what, how about i make a pull request for you, and you can use my code. What's the github link?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```js
bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
```

This line drains memory so hard. Now you have the URI of the image right?

```js
Uri filePath = data.getData();
```

Now use Picasso to load the image like below
1. If you want to send the image somewhere else:

```js
com.squareup.picasso.Target mTarget = new com.squareup.picasso.Target() {
                        @Override
                        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            

                        @Override
                        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                        }
                    };
                    
                    Picasso.with(mContext).load(filePath).into(mTarget);
```

2. If you want to Use the image in lower quality, Just do this:

```js
Picasso.with(mContext).load(filePath).centerInside().resize(YourWidth,YourHeight).into(imageview);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Bitmap` object in `MainActivity` is marked as static, I doubt why is that necessary.
Making it static makes Android cannot GC it when you start Main2Activity,
A potential reason of why you are running out of memory.

Try to change it to `private Bitmap bitmap`. It *might* solves your problem.

But generally passing a bitmap object over an Activity is rare.
Since you mentioned that the image is uploaded, it is much better to get an image URL from server after you have uploaded it, and then use some Image Library such as `Glide` or `Fresco` to load it from the internet.